# Flink, Aliasing more fields than we actually have

Tags: apache-flink

Flink 1.14, code snippet below works fine,

```
DataStream<Row> dataStream = env.fromElements(
         Row.of("Alice", 12),
         Row.of("Bob", 10),
         Row.of("Alice", 100));
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(dataStream).as("name", "score");
```

While below code throws error "Aliasing more fields than we actually have",

```
DataStreamSource<Row> ds = env.addSource(new MockSource());
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds).as("name", "score");
......

public static class MockSource implements SourceFunction<Row> {

        private volatile boolean running = true;

        @Override
        public void run(SourceContext<Row> ctx) throws Exception {
            while (running) {
                Row row = Row.of("Alice", 12);
                ctx.collect(row);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            running = false;
        }
}
```

These two appear to be inconsistent, could anyone please explain why Flink has this different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you need to explicitly register those fields via the `registerDataStream()` function prior to processing your data:

```
tableEnv.registerDataStream(
  "your-stream-name", 
  dataStream,
  "name, score"
);
```

You may also want to consider defining the types for your records as well similar to the example demonstrated in the following integration test from the Flink repository:

```
public void testRowRegisterRowWithNames() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
    StreamITCase.clear();

    List<Row> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(Row.of(1, 1L, "Hi"));
    data.add(Row.of(2, 2L, "Hello"));
    data.add(Row.of(3, 2L, "Hello world"));

    TypeInformation<?>[] types = {
        BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO,
        BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO,
        BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO};
    String names[] = {"a","b","c"};

    RowTypeInfo typeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(types, names);

    DataStream<Row> ds = env.fromCollection(data).returns(typeInfo);

    Table in = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds, "a,b,c");
    tableEnv.registerTable("MyTableRow", in);

    String sqlQuery = "SELECT a,c FROM MyTableRow";
    Table result = tableEnv.sql(sqlQuery);

    DataStream<Row> resultSet = tableEnv.toDataStream(result, Row.class);
    resultSet.addSink(new StreamITCase.StringSink());
    env.execute();

    List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();
    expected.add("1,Hi");
    expected.add("2,Hello");
    expected.add("3,Hello world");

    StreamITCase.compareWithList(expected);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rion for the answer. Yes, I know that I can use .returns(typeInfo) to avoid that error, what I don't know is, why one of my code snippets does need a .returns(typeInfo), while the other does not need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could can easily fix this by adding this method to your MockSource:

```java
    public static TypeInformation<Row> typeProduced() {
        return Types.ROW_NAMED(
                new String[] {"name", "score"},
                Types.STRING,
                Types.INT);
    }
```

The difference between the two situations is that this code

```java
DataStream<Row> dataStream = env.fromElements(
         Row.of("Alice", 12),
         Row.of("Bob", 10),
         Row.of("Alice", 100));
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(dataStream).as("name", "score");
```

actually runs in the client, while constructing the job graph that will be submitted to the cluster, and so the necessary type information is available when it's needed.

Whereas with this code

```
DataStreamSource<Row> ds = env.addSource(new MockSource());
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds).as("name", "score");
```

the run method in the source doesn't run in the client, so all that's known to the client building the job graph is that the source returns Rows containing who knows what.